# Trying to split a string into two variables

Tags: bash, shell, ifs

I'm trying to split a string into two variables (without having to use a while loop):

```
var="hello:world"
IFS=':' read var1 var2 <<< $var

echo "var1: $var1"
echo "var2: $var2"
```

but i'm not getting the desired result:

```
var1: 'hello world'
var2: ''
```

Could anybody please explain if it's possible to do it this way (or similar way)?

Comment: Note that this is not quite a duplicate; the code above is correct, but affected by a bug in 4.x (fixed in 4.3) that is not addressed in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Based on that, the appropiate behaviour is to reopen this (I just did) and accepted chepner's answer instead.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### This is a bug in Bash 4.2. See [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20163550/1983854) for a proper explanation.

---

It is about quotes. Use:

```
IFS=':' read var1 var2 <<< "$var"
                           ^    ^
```

instead of

```
IFS=':' read var1 var2 <<< $var
```

See result:

```
$ IFS=':' read var1 var2 <<< "$var"
$ echo "var1=$var1, var2=$var2"
var1=hello, var2=world
```

But

```
$ IFS=':' read var1 var2 <<< $var
$ echo "var1=$var1, var2=$var2"
var1=hello world, var2=
```

Comment: Great to read that, @coda, quoting is always important. Remember you can accept the answer if your question is already solved!

Comment: +1 This is one I don't understand (I'm not disputing it, just not understanding it). The setting of `IFS` should refer to the environment in which `read` is executed, but `$var` is expanded as part of the input redirection, which should *precede* the execution of `read`. Further, without quoting, it appears that the string is indeed one word, assigned to `var1`, but *then* split, as `var1` gets `hello` and `world`, not `hello:world`.

Comment: @chepner I found another funny behaviour: if you do `IFS=':' read var1 var2 <<< hello:bye` then it does split properly, while if it comes from a variable it does not.

Comment: Odd. I've filed a bug report, referencing this question. I noticed that using a here document (which should be equivalent to `... <<< "$var"`) also works.

Comment: @chepner interesting. With a here document you mean `<<< EOF ... EOF`? Also, could you keep me informed about what they say about the bug? Or a link to it should be perfect.

Comment: Sure. Right, `<<EOF$varEOF` (with newlines in the expected places) works the same as the quoted here string. Bugs are reported via e-mail, so no link to a bug tracker (yet).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41740/discussion-between-chepner-and-fedorqui)

Answer (score 14):

FYI for future readers:

After discussing this with the developers, it appears this is indeed a bug in `bash` 4.2, and has been fixed in the upcoming 4.3 release. From the [devel branch change log](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES-4.3?h=devel)

> rrrr. Fixed several problems with IFS when it appears in the temporary environment
>         and is used in redirections.

Although it's always a good idea to quote parameter expansions anyway, the OP's code should work as intended without quotes.

---

Here's an explanation of the bug. With the code

```
var="hello:world"
IFS=':' read var1 var2 <<< $var
```

the unquoted `$var` *should* be a single word, since it contains no character in the global  value of `IFS` (that is, no white-space). `read` should then see the string `hello:world`. Because it received two arguments, it should apply word-splitting using its local value of `IFS`, producing `hello` and `world` which are assigned to `var1` and `var2`, respectively.

The bug is that the here string appears to undergo partial splitting using the "leaked" value of `IFS` being passed to `read`. As a result, the string becomes `hello world`, but is still seen by `read` as a single word. Since that word does not contain a `:`, `read` does not split it into two words, and the entire string is assigned to `var1`.

In `bash` 4.3, as documented, the expansion of `$var` does not undergo word-splitting as the argument to the `<<<` operator; the code

```
var="hello:1:2 world"
IFS=: read var1 var2 <<< $var
```

sets `var1` to `hello` and `var2` to `1:2 world`.