# IFS change with Bash 4.2

Tags: bash, ifs

Running these commands gives expected results

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.11(2)-release

$ foo=(111 222 333)

$ IFS=, cat <<< "${foo[*]}"
111,222,333
```

However it appears with Bash 4.2 the IFS value is being ignored

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.0(1)-release

$ foo=(111 222 333)

$ IFS=, cat <<< "${foo[*]}"
111 222 333
```

What is causing this difference?

I found the answer here

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2014-03/msg00065.html

It looks as though this has been an error all along. According to Chet,
redirections should never have had access to the temp environment
(`IFS` in this case)

Comment: @fedorqui spooky, I'm on `GNU bash, version 4.2.45(2)-release (x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu)` and can reproduce the OP's behaviour

Comment: Reproduced with `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`. Output is `111 222 333`

Comment: For those interested, this is the changelog of bash 4.2: https://github.com/sunny256/bash/blob/master/CWRU/changelog Somewhere there must be some explanations, as it is from 4.1 to 4.2 when this changes.

Comment: This may also be loosely related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/20144593/1126841 (in that proper support of here strings and IFS seems to be an ongoing process).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find the behaviour of 4.2 correct as word splitting should happen first before evaluation of assignments:

```
IFS=, cat <<< "${foo[*]}"
```

I believe the new value of IFS should only affect `cat` and not `<<< "${foo[*]}"`.

The proper way to do that is

```
IFS=, eval 'cat <<< "${foo[*]}"'
```

And for a conservative approach we can use a function:

```
function t { cat <<< "${foo[*]}"; }
IFS=, t
```

I also have a guess that it's related to this:

```
m.  Fixed a bug that caused here documents to not be displayed correctly
    when attached to commands inside compound commands.
```

#### Update

Another confusing behavior can be found in 4.2 which is already fixed in 4.3. By doing `IFS=, cat <<< "${foo[*]}"`, `"${foo[*]}"` expands well as `"111 222 333"` (not affected by IFS) as shown by `cat` which is `111 222 333`. However when we do `IFS=, read bar <<< "${foo[*]}"; echo "$bar"`, the output would be `111,222,333` and would appear as if `"${foo[*]}"` expanded as `"111,222,333"`. This inconsistent behavior is no longer happening in Bash 4.3 and Bash 4.3's behavior is probably a fix.

Comment: +1 `cat` doesn't use `IFS`; things like `IFS=, read a b c` work because `read` is a `bash` builtin, not an external program.