# Processing string in BASH and count the number of a substring beeing seen

Tags: linux, string, bash, substring

If there is a string:

```
[[some_str,another_str],[some_str,the_str],[some_str,the_str],[some_str,whatever_str]]
```

And I want output like this:

```
another_str: 1
the_str: 2
whatever_str:1
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were willing to use awk, you could do something like this:

```
$ awk -F] -vRS="," '!(NR%2){++a[$1]}END{for(i in a)printf "%s: %s\n",i,a[i]}' <<<"[[some_str,another_str],[some_str,the_str],[some_str,the_str],[some_str,whatever_str]]"
whatever_str: 1
another_str: 1
the_str: 2
```

Set the field separator to `]` and the record separator to `,`. Count the occurrence of every second record. After all records have been processed, print the results.

Answer (score 4):

```
# read strings into an array, excluding [, ] and , characters
IFS='[],' read -r -a strings <<<'[[some_str,another_str],[some_str,the_str],[some_str,the_str],[some_str,whatever_str]]'

# store counts in an associative array
declare -A counts=()
for string in "${strings[@]}"; do
  [[ $string ]] || continue
  (( 'counts[$string]' += 1 ))
done

# iterate over that associative array and print counters
for string in "${!counts[@]}"; do
  echo "$string: ${counts[$string]}"
done
```

Comment: Requires bash 4 or greater for associative arrays. Also there's some IFS/read/heredoc/herestring bug that was fixed in some bash 4+ version that may or may not be relevant here (I forget the details unfortunately).

Comment: The current version as edited (thanks, @gniourf_gnioruf) works back on 4.0.35, so I don't believe we're depending on any recent fixes here.

Comment: Looks like the issue I was thinking of was leaking `IFS` to the redirection and was a `4.2` bug fixed in `4.3`. So yes, this is fine. (For the record it was never my intent to question that fact.)

Comment: Interesting -- I hadn't heard about that bug; will try to keep it in mind. Thanks!

Comment: Not the best resource but something at least. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929819/ifs-change-with-bash-4-2