# How to read an array from a variable split using IFS

Tags: bash

I am trying to initialize read an array by splitting a variable.

```
x=abc:def:gh
declare -a xa
# I want xa[0] = abc, xa[1] = def, and so on

IFS=: read -a xa <<< $x
echo ${#xa[@]} $xa ######### the above did not work
1 abc def gh

# but type the same value from console?
IFS=: read -a xa
abc:def:gh ########## this is what I typed in
echo ${#xa[@]} $xa ######### this worked
3 abc
```

How do put IFS to work when reading in a variable using <<< ?

Will appreciate your suggestions.

Also, here is my actual problem, just in case there are smarter solutions to it. I use SVN and different people are interested in knowing about different set of paths. In SVN post-commit, I want to filter the list of changes and raise an email to different groups of people according to their desires. So I thought I would set up something like below in hooks-env

```
NOTIFY_LIST=mailinglist:grep options:grep options:......
```

and then, in post-commit, parse the svnlook data to see if there was any candidate email. Is there a declarative way to say that a change in such and such paths are of interest to such and such lists of people?

Thanks
Dinesh

edit: tried combination of IFS and simply `xa=($x)`. So it appears `IFS=:` *cannot* be combined profitably with read. So I have a way to get my job done, but still curious what's happening?

```
IFS=: xa=($x) # the array is populated as expected
IFS=b xa=($x) # the array is populated as expected
```

Thanks again.

Comment: There were some bugs in earlier versions of `bash` when using `IFS` like this with here strings, at least some of which have been fixed in 4.3 See http://stackoverflow.com/q/20144593/1126841.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use more quotes!

```
IFS=: read -r -a xa <<<"$x"
```

...works as you expect.

Similarly, if you want to see the contents of an array accurately, `echo` is the wrong tool, **especially** when not quoting its arguments. Consider instead:

```
printf '%q\n' "${xa[@]}"
```

Comment: There was a bug in pre-4.3 versions of `bash`, since assuming the default value of `IFS`, the same string should be seen by `read` whether or not you quote `$x`. Without quotes, `$x` is incorrectly split into three words, but still treated as a single word by `read` when populating the array.

Comment: @chepner, thanks -- I didn't have a good explanation of _why_ quoting here fixed this; that clears it up.

Comment: @chepner, thanks for the succinct explanation. Mine is at 4.1.2

Comment: It's good that there is a simple workaround; 4.2 doesn't even seem to be widespread in distributions yet, so 4.3 as a default seems to be a ways out (even if distributions do leapfrog directly to 4.3).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `read`. `IFS` is all you need. (`set -f` or `set -o noglob on` as needed to prevent expansion):

```
#!/bin/bash
## if expansion of '*' or '?' is a concern, then uncomment the next line:
# set -f   # (or set -o noglob on)

x=abc:def:gh
IFS=$':'
arr=( $x )                          # simple assignment will split x


for ((i=0;i<${#arr[@]};i++)); do    # dump the loop values
    echo "arr[$i] ${arr[$i]}"
done
```

**output:**

```
arr[0] abc
arr[1] def
arr[2] gh
```

or with `set -f` and `x='*'`:

```
arr[0] *
```

Comment: This method is subject to pathname expansion or requires disabling pathname expansion. Try `x='*'; arr=($x)`.

Comment: Grr.. - you're right of course, but given the problem description I did not see pathname expansion as a criteria. But presuming a need to protect against all possibilities, then you can add `set -f` or `set -o noglob on`. (thanks for keeping me on my toes :)