# How can I split a string in KSH bash script?

Tags: ksh

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144593/trying-to-split-a-string-into-two-variables)

I referred this but I am not able to understand, how I can split:
Testing123 into Testing and 123

```
temp=${str%%:*} #only if there was colon in between but in my case there isn't.
```

If there was a space b/w them I would have gotten it to work.

Update:  I want to split letters and digits.

Character count would 5, TESTI, and then number would be 4.

so if it is TESTI123.

I want it to be var1 = testi, var2 = 123

```
var1=$(echo $STP | cut '[A-Z]' -f1)
var2=$(echo $STP | cut '[0-9]' -f1)
```

Even this didnt work, 
cut: [A-Z]: No such file or directory
cut: [0-9]: No such file or directory

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're confusing `bash` and `ksh` with shell scripts I assume by your question, they are two different shells. There's probably no need to be specific but be portable and use `#!/bin/sh` instead.

Comment: On what do you want to split? Boundary between letters and digits? Specific character count?

Comment: yes, I want to split letters and digits. Character count would 5, TESTI, and then number would be 4. so if it is TESTI123. I want it to be var1 = testi, var2 = 123

Answer (score 1):

Using sed

```
echo testi1234 | sed 's/[0-9]*//g'
echo testi1234 | sed 's/[a-z]*//g'
```

More complex, putting a space between them,

```
echo testi1234 | sed 's/\([A-Za-z]*\)\([0-9]*\)/\1 \2/'
```

EDIT: sed is not needed for the example the OP gives. Alternatives beneath.

In this case sed is to complex, you can just use tr :

```
echo testi1234 | tr -d "[a-zA-Z]"
echo testi1234 | tr -d "[0-9]"
```

When you want to use the internal shell syntax, you can also use

```
full=testi12345
start=${full%%[0-9]*}; echo ${start}
endstr=${full##*[[:lower:]]}; echo ${endstr}
```

Internal evaluation works fast, but is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the following questions is:
    echo "testi1234" |awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="5 4"}{print $1 RS $2}'

Now just need to store $1 and $2 in different variable and should be good to go. If anybody else has better answer please comment, I am open to learning new concepts.