# Bash: How to split a string and assign multiple variables

Tags: bash

I have to split a URL string and assign variables to few of the splits. Here is the string

```
http://web.com/sub1/sub2/sub3/sub4/sub5/sub6
```

I want to assign variables like below from bash

```
var1=sub2
var2=sub4
var3=sub5
```

How to do this in bash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to split a string into two variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144593/trying-to-split-a-string-into-two-variables)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
x="http://web.com/sub1/sub2/sub3/sub4/sub5/sub6"
IFS="/" read -r foo foo foo foo var1 foo var2 var3 foo <<< "$x"
echo "$var1 $var2 $var3"
```

Output:

```
sub2 sub4 sub5
```

Or with an array:

```
x="http://web.com/sub1/sub2/sub3/sub4/sub5/sub6"
IFS="/" read -r -a var <<< "$x"
echo "${var[4]}"
declare -p var
```

Output:

```
sub2
declare -a var='([0]="http:" [1]="" [2]="web.com" [3]="sub1" [4]="sub2" [5]="sub3" [6]="sub4" [7]="sub5" [8]="sub6")'
```

---

From `man bash`:

> `IFS`: The  Internal Field Separator that is used for word splitting after expansion and to split lines into words with the read builtin command.

Comment: For safety you should use: `read -r`: `do not allow backslashes to escape any characters`

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
IFS=/ read -r proto host dummy var1 dummy var2 var3 dummy <<< "$url"
```

Or `read -ra` to read into an array.  `read -r` makes backslash non-special.

This won't work in bash:

```
echo "$url" | read ...
```

because `read` would run in a subshell, [so the variables wouldn't be set in the parent shell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: or use this: `shopt -s lastpipe; set +m; echo "$url" | IFS="/" read -ra array`

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would be to assign the result of splitting into an array. For example:

```
IFS='/' read -a array <<< "http://web.com/sub1/sub2/sub3/sub4/sub5/sub6"
```

Unfortunately, this will create 3 'extraneous' elements, which you will have to take care of!

```
echo ${array[*]}
http: web.com sub1 sub2 sub3 sub4 sub5 sub6
```

EDIT: In here ${array[1]} is an empty element!

Comment: Don't forget to quote properly: `echo "${array[@]}"`