# Options menu with array

Tags: bash, sh

I am trying to make a script to get ip list from file and show it on screen with select option, and make ssh to that IP just by selecting. File is like below;

```
name1 1.1.1.1 
name2 2.2.2.2
name3 3.3.3.3
name4 4.4.4.4
```

Below script can read the list from file and shows it on screen as menu.It show both name and IPs for selection, but I want to show selection menu just by name. How can I achieve this?

```sh
PS3='Please enter your choice: '
readarray -t options < ./file.txt

select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
IFS=' ' read name ip <<< $opt
case  $opt  in  
       $opt) ssh $ip;; 

esac
done
```

---

```
1) name1 1.1.1.1
2) name2 2.2.2.2
3) name3 3.3.3.3
4) name4 4.4.4.4
Please enter your choice: 1
```

Comment: You've tagged your question [tag:sh], but you're using a command `readarray` which does not exist in POSIX shell. Are you sure this isn't a [tag:bash] question?

Comment: My guess is you are using a version of `bash` prior to 4.3, which had a bug which required `$opt` to be quoted in the here string for splitting to occur properly. Try `IFS=' ' read name ip <<< "$opt"`.

Comment: (To clarify, your code should work fine in `bash` 4.3 or later.)

Comment: (See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20163550/1126841)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is bash, not sh.

The `select` command isn't so frequently used. The problem you're having is that you're slurping whole lines in to `$options` with `readarray`, and the `select` command doesn't provide you with a way to format or trim the output.

One approach would be to split the array after reading it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a opt_host=()   # Initialize our arrays, to make sure they're empty.
declare -A opt_ip=()     # Note that associative arrays require Bash version 4.
readarray -t options < ./file.txt

for i in "${!options[@]}"; do
  opt_host[$i]="${options[$i]%% *}"             # create an array of just names
  opt_ip[${opt_host[$i]}]="${options[$i]#* }"   # map names to IPs
done

PS3='Please enter your choice (q to quit): '
select host in "${opt_host[@]}"; do
  case "$host" in
    "") break ;;  # This is a fake; any invalid entry makes $host=="", not just "q".
    *) ssh "${opt_ip[$host]}" ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is what I looking for.

Comment: His problem isn't with `options`, but with his `read` command properly splitting the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but to work around a bug in `bash` 4.0, 4.1, and 4.2, you need to quote the parameter expansion in the here string.

```
IFS=' ' read name ip <<< "$opt"
```