# Why does "read" here incorrectly populates array when used with unquoted here-string?

Tags: bash

I have encountered a strange behavior when using the `read` command and unquoted here-string when they still used to be subject to word-splitting (in older versions of `bash`). Please take a look at the following snippets:

Here `echo $line` splits on `IFS=:` and results in `echo a b c` - **OK**:

```
IFS=:
line=a:b:c

echo $line | { read -ra arr; declare -p arr; }
```

**Output:**

```
declare -a arr='([0]="a b c")'
```

---

`echo $line` results in `echo a:b:c` as it doesn't contain any characters from default `IFS` and `read` then splits on `IFS=:` and correctly populates the array - **OK**:

```
unset IFS
line=a:b:c

echo $line | { IFS=: read -ra arr; declare -p arr; }
```

**Output:**

```
declare -a arr='([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c")'
```

---

**Question:**

```
unset IFS
line=a:b:c
echo $line # outputs correctly a:b:c

IFS=: read -ra arr <<< $line
declare -p arr
```

**Output:**

```
a:b:c
declare -a arr='([0]="a b c")'
```

Here `<<< $line` should result in `<<< a:b:c` since `$line` doesn't contain anything from `IFS`. `read` should then correctly populate the array using `IFS=:` but the result is only one element, space delimited. **Why is that?**

I am using `GNU bash, version 4.1.17(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.11)` where here-strings used to be subject to word-splitting. Quoting **solves** the issue but I don't see how, in this particular case, word-splitting should mess things up since even the `echo $line ...` example works just fine.

In `GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` (where here-strings are no longer being split)  both unquoted and quoted versions work correctly.

Comment: Sounds like you assume word splitting happens on assignment. It actually happens on expansion.

Comment: @thatotherguy nope, I'm aware it happens on expansion :)

Comment: The [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) says that on here strings: `The word undergoes brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal. Pathname expansion and word splitting are not performed.` So i guess, maybe it was a bug between 4.1 and 4.4

Comment: @KamilCukJam yes it was. Word splitting was performed. But it behaves strangely when compared to `echo $line`.

Comment: There are three snippets of code, to which `echo $line` are you referring?

Comment: @KamilCuk 2nd vs 3rd. In 2nd the word splitting behaves as expected. It doesn't not in the 3rd, when here string is used.

Comment: Both `echo $line` are ok. In the 2nd, it gets `echo 'a:b:c' | IFS=: read -ra arr`, so echo is not spliting, spliting is done by `read`. In the third IFS is unset when `echo $line` is done, so line is also not spliting on `:` when echoing.

Comment: @KamilCukMe yes, I understand that. As I said, I was confused by the behavior of word splitting when used with here-string and `read`. See the accepted answer for explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in bash version 4.2 (and apparently some 4.1.x versions), which was fixed in version 4.3. See this [bug-bash thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2013-11/msg00058.html), which references [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144593/trying-to-split-a-string-into-two-variables); there is an explanation of the bug in [@chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20163550/1566221) to that question.