# Bash IFS, getting zapped in function call

Tags: linux, bash

Platform CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810, working in bash.
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

This is an idiom I've seen recommended for parsing text in bash in general and in particular for returning multiple values from a function.

```
IFS=":" read A B <<< $(echo ONE:TWO)
```

I'm getting unexpected behaviour when I call a function, **yyy** in the example here

```
IFS=":" read Y1 Y2 <<< $(yyy)
```

where **yyy** itself also wants to do a similar call.

The effect is that that within yyy() even though I explicitly specify the IFS

```
 IFS=":" read C1 C2 <<< $( echo "A:B" )
```

The fields are parsed, but both values are assigned to C1, it gets the value "A B". If the function is called in isolation it works as expected.

This is a test case, distilled down from a much larger script. I want to know what is happening with IFS here. In the failure case (the second example below) setting IFS=":" in the caller somehow cause the result fields to be aggregated. The first and third calls to yyy() below work as expected, output shown after the code.

```
#!/bin/bash

debug() { echo "$1" 1>&2 ; }

yyy() {
    debug "in yyy"
    # why are the two values assigned to A here if the caller specified IFS?
    IFS=":" read A B <<< $(echo ONE:TWO)
    debug "A=$A"
    debug "B=$B"

    echo "$A:$B"
}

    # this works as expected
    read Y1 Y2 <<< $(yyy)
    echo -e "===\n"

    # this cause the read in yyy() to aggregate
    IFS=":" read Y1 Y2 <<< $(yyy)
    echo -e "===\n"

    # This is a workaround that enables yyy() to work correctly
    # But why do I need to do this?
    OUT="$(yyy)"
    IFS=":" read Y1 Y2 <<< $(echo $OUT)
```

This is the output

```
in yyy 
A=ONE B=TWO

===

in yyy 
A=ONE TWO B=

===

in yyy 
A=ONE B=TWO
```

Note that in the second case `A` gets the value `ONE TWO`

Comment: [Can't reproduce repl link](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/AwfulEasyRuntimes). I get `A=ONE B=TWO` on separate lines for second case. Note that `<<< $(echo )` is strange use of `echo`, just `<<<"ONE:TWO"`. What bash version are you using? `yyy` is executed in a subshell - it shouldn't have any influence on the parent shell.

Comment: The echo syntax is because in real life I'm calling something else. I agree that the behaviour is unexpected - however it's the behaviour **in** yyy that's unexpected, the parent seems to be affecting yyy. Very interesting that your shell works as expected.

Comment: I note that you are using GNU bash, version 4.4.12 whereas I'm back a few versions 4.2.46

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in `bash-4.2` as discussed here, [IFS incorrectly splitting herestrings in bash 4.2](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1196566). Should work on the versions above that.

These are the results on the same version as you have -  GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2). When I ran the function `yyy` in debug mode ( by setting `set -x` in prompt ).

```
++ IFS=:
++ read A B
+++ echo ONE:TWO
++ debug 'A=ONE TWO'
++ echo 'A=ONE TWO'
A=ONE TWO
++ debug B=
++ echo B=
B=
++ echo 'ONE TWO:'
```

The above is snippet of the output from the debug mode output. As you can see when the `echo ONE:TWO` is printed as a result of the command substitution, no word splitting is expected to happen because the line doesn't contain any character of the default `IFS` value (space/tab or a newline)

So you would expect reading the the whole string with `IFS=:` expected to split the string and put the values in the constituent variables `A` and `B`, but somehow the `:` character is lost and a string `ONE TWO` is stored as the first variable value.

Look at the output of the function execution in GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1) which exhibits the right behavior.

```
++ IFS=:
++ read A B
+++ echo ONE:TWO
++ debug A=ONE
++ echo A=ONE
A=ONE
++ debug B=TWO
++ echo B=TWO
B=TWO
++ echo ONE:TWO
```

There have been lot of `IFS` related bugs up to version 4.4.0 [bash/CHANGES](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/bash/blob/master/CHANGES). So a personal recommendation is to upgrade your `bash` version to a more recent stable one. Also see [Trying to split a string into two variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20144593/5291015)

***Similar bug on version 4.4.0(1)-release***

You would expect the `ONE:TWO` to be unmodified when the `$(..)` is expanded because for reasons mentioned earlier. But here too the delimit character is lost and the variable `A` is set to `ONE TWO`

```
IFS=":" read A B <<< $(echo ONE:TWO)
echo "$A"
ONE TWO
```

Surprisingly the above code works on 4.2.46(2), which means the 4.4.0(1) broke a functionality which used to work in the earlier releases.

Comment: Thanks for the investigation. It's reassuring to know that this should work.